# UWP XAML Border: unexpected overflow

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

While thinkering a bit I found some (for me) unexpected behaviour of the `Border` element in XAML. That is when the `BorderThickness` of a side is set to 0, there appears to be an overflow of the border on the side adjacent.

To demonstrate I made a quick sample

```
<Page
x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Height="20" Width="300" Fill="Blue" Margin="50, 30, 0 ,0"  />
        <Border Height="20" Width="300" Background="Green" Margin="50, 50, 0 ,0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0,0,0,4" />
    </Canvas>
</Page>
```

This results in the visual representation following (zoomed in for better visibility)

[image: 1px overlay on left side]

As you can see, the red border overlaps the actual `Border` element by 1px. The blue `Rectangle` is to verify, that it is not the green background but the red border being out of place.

Now the interesting part. When I edit the code so `BorderThickness="4,0,0,4"`, the left overflow is gone but instead there is one on the top.

[image: 1px overlay on top side]

Now to my questions:

1. Is this overflow the expected behaviour for `Border`?
2. Is there a way to avoid this without using multiple `Rectangle` and thus further increase complexity?

Comment: Try Margin="0,50,0,0" for Green background and check what happens.

Comment: @RahulJha well the `Border` element gets shifted to the left as you'd expectand the overflow isn't visible anymore because it is outside the bounds of the Page and Window.

Comment: What's your screen's resolution? Maybe try disabling `UseLayoutRounding` on your `Canvas`?

Comment: @JustinXL on the device I reported a standard 1920*1080. But I am able to reproduce the behaviour on a SP4 with 2736*1824 at 200% aswell as on a L950XL with 1440*2560 at 350%. Tried disabling `UseLayoutRounding`, didn't help.

Comment: Why use the border's thickness as a line? A `borderthickness` has four sides, I think this overflow is considered for other sides. Try to imagine how the bottom `borderthickness` link up with the left one? I recomend you to use `link` element as follows: `  <Line Margin="50,50,0,0" StrokeThickness="4"  X1="0" Y1="0"    X2="300" Y2="0"    Stroke="Red"  ></Line>`